# How do I prevent properties from being added to an empty object in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript type checker seems to accept the following code. Why is that? Can I somehow make it more strict?

```js
const foo: {} = {bar: 123}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by defining the type as `Record<any, never>`.

```js
const foo: Record<any,never> = {} // this works
const bar: Record<any,never> = {bar: 123} // this creates error as expected
```

Comment: It would be nice if I could ban `{}` somehow. Maybe some eslint plugin would let me blacklist such dangerous type signatures.

Comment: Use Interfaces to make sure you have the desired signature, this doesn't help anybody. e.g. `interface Foo {
    bar: number
}`

Comment: @MikeS. It solved my problem. I had `type UrlFactory<O extends { }> = (o: O) => string` and since I did `const foo: UrlFactory<{}> = ...` I was able to accidentally call it with `foo({ bar: 123 })` without the error being caught. I changed the type to `UrlFactory<Record<any, never>>` and the error gets caught just fine after this change. The only problem that remains is preventing others from accidentally using `{}` again.

Answer (score 1):

The [object](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object) type is pretty broad. It’s perfectly valid for it to be either empty or have properties.

I would recommend using the [null](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#object) type instead of an empty object and a type or interface if you wish to validate object properties.

See [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHIBGcUAXMiAK4C2R0uAvrrgG6nIyYUZYA+lKgBshyALyCRLLlgl5CxUhQCMAJgDMTIA)

```js
interface Foo {
    bar: number
}

var foo: Foo | null = null

foo = {
    bar: 123
}
```

Comment: Making the type nullable would work in some situations. However, it does not work in situations where the type needs to be an object since `null` is not  an object. For examples `type A<T extends {}> = T; type B = A<{bar: number}|null>` would not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
const foo: { [index: string]: never } = {} // no error
const bar: {[index : string]: never } = {a:1} // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAuGBvGBtAlmAJgUwA8VoAnHAcwF0Ux8A3fUmAXxgF402B6bmMEDCakQpALAAoUJFgAjAIakUqbHiIwSUcmGpI6jUm06p5SAIw8+w0UA)

Comment: This is essentially the same as my `Record<any, never>` solution.

Answer (score 0):

any object is asignable to {}. But often, when you try to use it after you will not have the properties from the type :

```
const foo: {} = {bar: 123}
foo.bar // error : Property 'bar' does not exist on type '{}'
```

You should define a type first, or infer the type on your declaration :

```
// with a type (an interface would also work)
type Foo = {
    bar: number;
}

const foo: Foo = {bar: 123};
foo.bar // type: number

// with inference :
const foo = {bar: 123};
foo.bar // type: number
```

Comment: This answers the opposite question. My question was about making the type more strict. This answer focuses on making the type less strict.